# Iterates controls for checkboxes in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to go through all the check boxes in *form.tab* and mark them as not selected. I found this was the right decision:

```
     foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
     {
         CheckBox cb = c as CheckBox;
         if (cb! = null & & cb.Checked)
         {
            cb.Checked = false;
         }
     }
```

But it does not work! And I do not understand why. I watched the debugger and `cb` is `null`. Why can this be? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Maybe your checkboxes not in the form but in other container?

Comment: No:( Main_form.j1checkbox1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the first line from:

```
this.Controls
```

to

```
this.tab.Controls
```

Your current code is looping though the controls directly on the form. You need to loop through the controls on the tab.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, the CheckBoxes are contained in some container, therefore you have to do some recursive lookup or iterating directly over the [Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx)-collection of this container.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void FindControls(Control Page)
{
     foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
     {
          if (ctrl is CheckBox)
          {
              if (cb! = null & & cb.Checked)
              {                   
                   cb.Checked = false;                
              }
          }
          else 
          {
              if (ctrl.Controls.Count > 0)
              {
                   FindControls(ctrl);
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the checkboxes controls are not in the form maybe they in other container like Group box or Panel